# R to create a new variable, which is the mean of other several variables

Tags: r

I am a beginner of R, recently I met some troubles in creating a new variable with mutate() function. The data frame "evs" has six variables:v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6. I hope to calculate their average and assign the average to a new variable "intp.trust" ,so I use the following commands:

```
evs <- mutate(evs,intp.trust= mean("v1","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6"))
```

But the new varriable "intp.trust" turns to have only *NA*. Is there anything wrong with my command? I hope someone can help me with it.

Comment: Use `evs %>% mutate(intp.trust = rowMeans(across(v1:v6), na.rm = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In   `dplyr`

```
evs %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(intp.trust = mean(v1:v4))
```

Another solution:

```
evs$intp.trust <- apply(evs[1:6], 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
      v1       v2       v3       v4 intp.trust
1 3.386651 7.651824 3.537067 7.490539   5.516520
2 9.749669 6.686065 9.328821 1.676758   6.860328
3 1.231070 4.339285 9.274955 1.046044   3.972839
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rowMeans` as it is vectorized

```
library(dplyr)
evs <- evs %>% 
   mutate(intp.trust = rowMeans(across(v1:v6), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Corrected, I missed out the required `c`*

I believe `mean` doesn't work over multiple vectors, so you need to tell dplyr to do the operation row-by-row. You can do this by using the "rowwise" function, i.e.:

```
evs <- evs %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(intp.trust = mean(c(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)))
```